# Username Get back to calling point after successful SAML authentication

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I want to get the SAML response back to the calling service when I am calling using from other web API.
I want to further validate the user in database where I am struggling any hint?

Try various redirect options but not getting how to return back to the point from where I have left with the user details.

Answer (score 0):

The IdP should redirect back to the endpoint configured in the IdP. Where you can do a new redirect to the `returnUrl`, please se the sample:

- https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L31
- https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L62